# Could not find adb Please set the ANDROID_HOME exception- Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium, automation, appium

I have just started learning `Appium` using **`C#`**. Getting below error while executing first Test

> Message: System.InvalidOperationException : An unknown server-side
>   error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Could not
>   find adb Please set the ANDROID_HOME environment variable with the
>   Android SDK root directory path. TearDown :
>   System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object.

I have added `ANDROID_HOME` variable in my machine Environment option(not in Visual Studio IDE)

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: do you having problem finding android directory or what?

Comment: Yeah! I don't know where that directory is in VS? Thank you.

Comment: why in Visual Studio?

Comment: I am using Visual Studio IDE with C# for Appium.

Comment: ok then you have to add the ANDROID_HOME enviromental variable first

Comment: which OS do you used ?

Comment: I don't know where to add en. variable in visual studio. I am using Winows 10.

Comment: does the below solution work for you?

Comment: download **android-sdk** and add it to the system environment path as mention by @akshaypatil

Comment: @SubanDhyako - His answer actually worked. I have already added environment variable but I didn't restart my PC. After restarting PC now that error has gone. Getting another error. Device not found :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Set the Android SDK Home Environment Variable**

To set the Android SDK home environment variable, do the following:

1.Click Start.

2.Right-click Computer, and then select Properties.

3.Click Advanced system settings.

4.On the Advanced tab, click Environment Variables.

5.Under User variables, click New.

6.For Variable name, type the following value: ANDROID_HOME

7.For Variable value, type the path to the parent directory where your Android SDK is installed. For instance: C:\Android\android-sdk

8. Click OK until you have closed all dialog boxes. Do not click Cancel.
9. Restart your computer.

**Note:**  You must restart your machine.

Happy to help let me know if you need more help regarding this...